# click function in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I made a registration form on a web page and now I want to see a textarea is getting visible if you click a checkbox. 
Who knows how to set up further this code?
Below the code I have until now.

```
$("input").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('partner').innerHTML = "[here I have to put the name / id of the textarea]";
}
```

Comment: If partner is the id of your textarea, adnd it's currently hidden with `display: none`, something along the lines of `document.getElementById('partner').style.display = 'block';` should work. If not, then provide more code.

Comment: Hi neilsimp1 thanks for your quick answer only it won't work :(

Comment: Then you're probably going to need to show some more code or provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Hi neilsimp1 thanks for your quick answer only it won't work :(

`$("partner").click(function() {
            document.getElementById('input_60').style.display = 'block';
        }
`
[printscreen][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6MnSV.png

So when input_57 is clicked, input 60 needs to be visible

Answer (score 0):

Hi neilsimp1 thanks for your quick answer only it won't work :(

`$("partner").click(function() {
            document.getElementById('input_60').style.display = 'block';
        }`

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MnSV.png)

So when input_57 is clicked, input 60 needs to be visible

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove that answer and move that into your question, since it's not really an answer... Either way, I can see what's going on now.

1. Your checkbox has a `name` of input_57, but no `id`. I'd try adding `id="input_57"` (or whatever id you want to give it)
2. If clicking on this is supposed to show input_60, then `$("partner").click` isn't what you want.

   `$('#input_57').on('click', function(){
       document.getElementById('input_60').style.display = 'block';
   });`

This is assuming that input_60 has `display:none;`

Comment: From your second screenshot - `$('partner')` this is trying to select an element with `partner` as a tag name, which doesn't exist. If you want the `input_57` checkbox click to trigger showing this, then you want `$('#input_57').on('click', ...`. I'd still recommend putting this into a jsfiddle if you still can't get it so myself or someone else can see all the code in question.

Comment: OK I will try, thanks for your time and the tip about the code, wil delete the images